# JSON - PL/SQL ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed

Tags: json, plsql

Sample JSON:

```
[
  {
    "term-id": "BA000000",
    "bank-id": "111",
    "location": "Poslovalnica banke",
    "address": "Cankarjeva ulica 2",
    "city": "Ljubljana",
    "post-code": "1000",
    "printer": "true",
    "deposit": "false",
    "accessible": "true",
    "cards": "DECPVR",
    "special-payments": "false",
    "BNA": "false",
    "transaction-receipt": "true",
    "latitude": 46.051671,
    "longitude": 14.505122
  }
]
```

I am trying to utilize pljson:

```
declare
  w_req t_http_request := t_http_request();
  w_res t_http_response;
  w_vrni clob;
  w_json pljson;
  w_jsonValue pljson_value;
  w_jsonList pljson_list;
  w_test varchar2(100);
begin
  w_req.url := 'https://api.bankart.si/psd2/hub/v1/' || 'ATMList';
  w_req.add_header('x-ibm-client-id', 'client-id');
  w_res := https_client.doGet (w_req, 'DB');
  w_vrni := hibis_util.convertBlobToClob(w_res.content_blob,'AL32UTF8');
  
  w_jsonList := pljson_list(w_vrni);
  if w_jsonList is not null and w_jsonList.count > 0 then
    for i in 1..w_jsonList.count loop
      w_json := pljson(w_jsonList.get(i));
      w_jsonValue := w_json.get('term-id');
      w_test := w_jsonValue.get_string;
      dopl(w_test);
    end loop;
  end if;
end;
```

I'm able to extract, I don't know maybe location or address values from this JSON, but when I want to extract elements term-id or bank-id I get error PL/SQL ORA-30625: method dispatch on NULL SELF argument is disallowed. Maybe because of "-" sign between?

Anybody with some idea? Thx.

Comment: You're trying to call method on an object variable which is null. I'm suspecting it's maybe w_jsonValue variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making it too complicated. :) Try:

```
set serveroutput on
declare
   v_json pljson;
   v_test varchar2(100);
   v_jsonl pljson_list := pljson_list('[
  {
    "term-id": "BA000000",
    "bank-id": "111",
    "location": "Poslovalnica banke",
    "address": "Cankarjeva ulica 2",
    "city": "Ljubljana",
    "post-code": "1000",
    "printer": "true",
    "deposit": "false",
    "accessible": "true",
    "cards": "DECPVR",
    "special-payments": "false",
    "BNA": "false",
    "transaction-receipt": "true",
    "latitude": 46.051671,
    "longitude": 14.505122
  }
]');
begin
   for i in 1..v_jsonl.count loop
      v_json := pljson(v_jsonl.get(i));
      v_test := v_json.get('term-id').get_string;
      dbms_output.put_line(v_test);
   end loop;
end;
```